# Check migration before running new migration in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, devops, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We have several migration tasks running in our ECS task definition services. but I want to automate that before running new migration task , it should check if there is already a migration task running and if there is already one running , it should wait until one migration task is completed and closed and then only it should run another migration .can somehelp help me with this !!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know how to check if there is already an older version of a task running in ECS before deploying new version . It should be automated that in case the older version is already running than new version should not start